# UIPickerView works properly in simulator, but *looks* empty on device

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, simulator

I have an app with a UIPickView which works perfectly in a simulator, but when I run the app on a device, it appears empty.

Important note: it only **looks** empty because I still can scroll it and selected item is changing.

```
class ViewController: UIInputViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fontPicker.delegate = self
    fontPicker.dataSource = self
    fontPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
  }

  let fonts: [FontFamily] = [...]

  var currentFont: FontFamily = FontFamily()

  func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    1
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    fonts.count
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    fonts[row].title
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    currentFont = fonts[row]
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide code examples

Comment: Change your device theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's most likely happening is your text is white and the background is also white, so your items are there, they just look invisible.

You can try overriding the attributed title functions and return an NSAttributedString with it's foregroundColor attribute set to black.

Alternatively, you can override the view for row function and construct and return a UILabel styled the way you want.

You can find a bunch of examples of these here on stack overflow or by doing a quick Google search.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your device Dark Mode is turn on or off ... hopefully solve the issue